# Cast ORMLite object to Serialize for put extra

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I need to send ORMLite object to another activity, so I am using putExtra for it. But for that I need to cast this object to serializable object.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is your question?  I'm not understanding.  Why don't you just make your entity Serializable?

Answer (score 1):

I used this kind of code to send object of one class, but I think it should work for you

**ActivityA:**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ...
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    intent.putExtra("TAG", ORMLiteObject);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**ActivityB:**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ...
    ORMLite ORMobject = (ORMLite) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("TAG);
// or try this one
    // ORMLite ORMobject = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("TAG");
}
```